# Longtable and arydshln problem

Tags: tables, arydshln

I need some help.

My `longtable` was all right until I wanted to insert one horizontal dash line. That's why I put package `arydshln` (which caused troubles). Even before I used `\hdashline` code, my result got this appearance: vertical line got extended and covered the row of a page number

[image: here]

and in the end of `longtable`, last row is missing a vertical line

[image: here]

I just can't figure out where is the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
TABLE
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\begin{centering}
\begin{longtable}{@{}r |  r   r   r   r   r   r}
\caption{Table}\\
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{AA}&  BB &  CC &  DD\\ 
\specialrule{2.0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\endfirsthead
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{AA} &  BB &  CC &  DD\\ 
\specialrule{2.0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\endhead
11 & A & B & C & D\\ 
22 & A & B & C & D\\ 
33 & A & B & C & D\\ 
44 & A & B & C & D\\ 
55 & A & B & C & D\\ 
66 & A & B & C & D\\ 
77 & A & B & C & D\\ 
88 & A & B & C & D\\ 
99 & A & B & C & D\\ 
111 & A & B & C & D\\ 
222 & A & B & C & D\\ 
333 & A & B & C & D\\
00 & A & B & C & D\\
11 & A & B & C & D\\ 
22 & A & B & C & D\\ 
33 & A & B & C & D\\ 
44 & A & B & C & D\\ 
55 & A & B & C & D\\ 
66 & A & B & C & D\\ 
77 & A & B & C & D\\ 
88 & A & B & C & D\\ 
99 & A & B & C & D\\ 
000 & A & B & C & D\\
111 & A & B & C & D\\ 
222 & A & B & C & D\\ 
444 & A & B & C & D\\
555 & A & B & C & D\\
666 & A & B & C & D\\
777 & A & B & C & D\\
888 & A & B & C & D\\
999 & A & B & C & D\\
\end{longtable}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

(code edited)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please complete your code so that it will compile when copy-pasted. That way, we can reproduce the problem right away.

Comment: To further clarify: I'm not sure what the problem is meant to be. When I add the `document` environment, remove the vertical dots and compile, I get the output I'd expect. So either I don't understand the issue or it is not reproducible even with a completed version of your code. [Last row has as many vertical lines as the preceding two rows.]

Comment: I  edited the code and still experiencing the problem. First part of `longtable` got too long vertical line, and other part of `longtable` (that is printed on other page) got a too short vertical line and it doesnt cover whole table (last row to be exactly)

Answer (score 2):

Some comments:

- There is no environment called `centering`. There's one called `center`, though.
- Inserting the instruction `\centering` is *not needed* since a `longtable` environment is centered by default.
- You may want to replace `\specialrule{2.0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` with `\midrule[2pt]` and `\cline{2-7}` with `\cmidrule{2-7}`. By the way, a rule that's 2pt thick looks very very heavy. What are you trying to achieve by using such a thick rule (other than distract the reader)?
- Since you're using the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal lines, why insert a vertical rule at all? They're not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}  %% "times" is deprecated
\usepackage{graphicx,longtable,amsmath,booktabs,setspace}
\doublespacing
%%\usepackage{arydshln} % not needed, right?

\begin{document}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont

\begin{longtable}{@{} r *{4}{r} @{}}
\caption{Table}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& \kern1.5em AA & BB &  CC &  DD\\ 
\midrule[2pt]
\endfirsthead
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& AA &  BB &  CC &  DD\\ 
\midrule[2pt]
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
11 & A & B & C & D\\ 
22 & A & B & C & D\\ 
33 & A & B & C & D\\ 
44 & A & B & C & D\\ 
55 & A & B & C & D\\ 
66 & A & B & C & D\\ 
77 & A & B & C & D\\ 
88 & A & B & C & D\\ 
99 & A & B & C & D\\ 
111 & A & B & C & D\\ 
222 & A & B & C & D\\ 
333 & A & B & C & D\\
00 & A & B & C & D\\
11 & A & B & C & D\\ 
22 & A & B & C & D\\ 
33 & A & B & C & D\\ 
44 & A & B & C & D\\ 
55 & A & B & C & D\\ 
66 & A & B & C & D\\ 
77 & A & B & C & D\\ 
88 & A & B & C & D\\ 
99 & A & B & C & D\\ 
000 & A & B & C & D\\
111 & A & B & C & D\\ 
222 & A & B & C & D\\ 
444 & A & B & C & D\\
555 & A & B & C & D\\
666 & A & B & C & D\\
777 & A & B & C & D\\
888 & A & B & C & D\\
999 & A & B & C & D\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uff, my bad. I am a fresh starter (writing thesis for the first time in LaTeX) and was experimenting with `tabular`, `longtable`,... so I mixed things apparently.

Thanks for rule suggestion. Haven't realized it was so thick, I just wanted it to be slightly thicker than rest of lines.
About vertical rule, I have a lots of data in tables, 10 columns or more and it would be a lot easier to read it if specific columns are separated with line.

About that package `arydshln` in code, I need one dashed horizontal line in the table (that i haven't put in yet) but that package messed my vertical line.

Comment: @AuroraNord - It's mostly an illusion that vertical lines make a table easier to read. Lines in tables are visual separators. If a vertical line is truly necessary, it's probably the case that the material being separated is so different as to call into question why it's even presented in one table, rather than two (or more) tables.